# How do I get this code to continue to pick a random value from my table? Lua Code

Tags: lua

```
if gdt.LedButton0.ButtonState
then gdt.Lcd0.Text = Random
else gdt.Lcd0.Text = Text
end

Random = ( myTable[ math.random( #myTable ) ] )
```

I want the code to continue to pick a random value from the table when a button is pressed. Currently, it picks a value the first time it is pressed and sticks with that value until the program is reset

I have tried looping the code, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose `Random` before or in your `if ... then ... else ... end`
Like...

```
-- Maybe you need to set math.randomseed() first?
-- Then...
-- math.randomseed(math.random(os.time()))

if gdt.LedButton0.ButtonState then
  Random = myTable[math.random(#myTable)]
  gdt.Lcd0.Text = Random
else
  gdt.Lcd0.Text = Text
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to [`seed()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) it.

```
local function SomeFuncThatGetsExecutedOnceAtStartOfProgram()
    math.randomseed(os.time())
end
```

(where `math` is a local reference to the Math library and `os` is a local reference to the Operating System library)
Then in your function:

```
Random = ( myTable[ math.random( #myTable ) ] )
```

(although, keep in mind `#` doesn't really return the number of items in a table)